# Best way to have bundled In App Purchases on IOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm working on an application had will have multiple In App purchases.  Lets say for example that we have items1 - items10 for sale, all non consumable.  We would also like to have "Bundles" of these items so Bundle1 has items1 - items5 in it. We want to have each item 1.99 but 5.99 for the group.  I looked around but I haven't seen if there is any protocol for handling this.  Is it even allowed?

What if the user has bought items2, are they still allowed to buy a bundle which also contains that item even though it would be cheaper than buying the rest individually?

If we had a separate IAP for the bundle it would make restoring more difficult, if they had bought a bundle, then try to re-buy one of the items individually, instead of apple telling them they already bought it, it would treat it as a new purchase.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Any followup on this? I'm in the same situation now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented bundles in several apps and in all of them we have created a separate IAP productID for the bundles in addition to the individual item productIDs. This allows you full control over prices.

Then we just handle the activate/restore in the "provideContent:(NSString *)productId receipt:(NSData*)receipt" method. It is no more difficult to unlock multiple items as it is a single item.

We have not really worried to much about whether the user has already purchased an item that is in the bundle, or if they try to purchase something they already own. We pretty much leave it up to the user to keep that straight. If they want to spend their money, we let them.

You could always run a check before you submit the transaction to Apple to see if they already own the item and let them know.

Comment: Thanks, I guess if I handle all the restoring correctly then there shouldn't be much to worry about.